# Are dbId guaranteed to be consistent in the instanceTree

Tags: autodesk-forge

When loading in the instanceTree, can it be assumed that the dbIds given to each node will be the same dbIds given to the same nodes on another load of the same model tree?

Answer (score 0):

You should expect dbIds to remain constant across multiple sessions for the same translated file. However, you should not expect dbIds to remain the same if you edit a file in the original design application and then retranslate the file.